# Entity Framework defining tables in db context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I am buys designing the model below:

```
 public class LogModel
    {
        public class UserActivityLogs
        {
            [Key]
            public int id { get; set; }

            //Id of the user
            public string userId { get; set; }

            //Time of the log
            public DateTime time { get; set; }

            public LogActions action { get; set; }
        }

        // Types of actions to log
        public class LogActions
        {
            [Key]
            public int id { get; set; }

            public string name { get; set; }

            public string description { get; set; }
        }     
    }
```

Now what I would like to know is do I need to add a table in the context for `Logactions` as well as `UserActivityLogs` or will EF see that the two tables are linked and create the `log action` table automatically?

Also have I specified my relationships correctly? What I was aiming for is that I can define multiple types of Logactions and then a userlog will then have a single log action associated to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use nested classes, it's a needless complication. Use namespaces to organize classes.

Second, don't use plural names for classes. One instance of class represents one entity. Also, use CamelCase names for properties.

Third, yes, Entity Framework will be aware of the associations between the two classes and create a database model with two tables and a foreign key.

So this leaves you with:

```
namespace MyApp.LogModel
{
    public class UserActivityLog
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public LogAction LogAction { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogAction
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }     
}
```